# How do I background a job quietly?

Tags: csh

Using csh, how do I put a job in the background without generating any output?

```
[prompt] job &
[1] 5103
```

I want to eliminate the line `[1] 5103`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked:

```
/bin/csh -cf "job &" >& /dev/null
```